# Get value of aggregate xpath function in Selenium Java

Tags: xpath, selenium-java

I'm trying to get the index of a `<tr>` element based on the contents of its `<td>` elements in Selenium using xpath.

```java
String xpath = "count(//tr[td[text()='Column Value A'] and td[text()='Column Value B']]/preceding-sibling::*)"
WebElement count = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath))
```

However, I'm getting this exception.

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression count(//tr[td[text()='Column Value A'] and td[text()='Column Value B']]/preceding-sibling::*) because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.
```

Is there any way for Selenium to return the value of an aggregate xpath function?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You XPATH seems to be wrong.

```
String xpath = "//tr[td[text()='Column Value A'] and td[text()='Column Value B']]/preceding-sibling::*"
WebElement count = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath))
```

Please check this out.

Reg your query

> I'm trying to get the index of a  element based on the contents of
> its  elements in Selenium using xpath.

What I usually do is, maintain 3 different locators for header and row.

```
By dataRows = By.xpath("//tr[./td]");
By cellData = By.xpath("//td");
By tableHeaders = By.xpath("//tr/th");
```

If we want to check whether the first row contains the specified value, we need to call this method as:
`int columnIndex = getColumnIndex(0,"Ahamed Abdul Rahman");`

```
public int getColumnIndex(int rowIndex, String value) {
    List<WebElement> rowthElements = driver.findElements(dataRows).get(rowIndex).findElements(cellData);
    return IntStream.range(0, rowthElements.size())
            .filter(i -> rowthElements.get(i).getText().equals(value))
            .findFirst().orElse(-1);
}
```

This method returns the header name at that column's index:

```
public String getHeaderName(int columnIndex) {
    return driver.findElements(tableHeaders).get(columnIndex).getText();
}
```

Doing directly in Xpath may be possible but I found this easier for me.